# Questions about Sqlite3 : saving tuples and get back data

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm on a python project, and I use Sqlite3 to store some users' data.

I've got 2 problems however : 
First, I don't know how to save a tuple : I need to save something like ('RSA', 6584,786) in my Sqlite table

Here's the code:

```
def ajouter_utilisateur(identifiant, prenom, adresse_mail, mdp, cle_privee, cle_publique):

commande = sqlite3.connect ('Base_de_donnees.db')
curseur = commande.cursor()

curseur.execute ('''SELECT id FROM utilisateurs''')
id_utilises = curseur.fetchall() # crée une liste [(0,),(1,)...]

nouvel_id = 0
for id_utilise in id_utilises:
    if nouvel_id <= id_utilise [0]:
        nouvel_id = id_utilise [0] + 1 # le nouvel id est supérieur au plus grand id déja présent

curseur.execute ('''INSERT INTO utilisateurs VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)''', (nouvel_id, identifiant, prenom, adresse_mail, mdp, cle_privee, cle_publique))
commande.commit()
commande.close()

>>> ajouter_utilisateur ('guil','guil','mail','password',('RSA',587,78), (577,789))


File xx, line 40, in ajouter_utilisateur
curseur.execute ('''INSERT INTO utilisateurs VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)''', 
(nouvel_id, identifiant, prenom, adresse_mail, mdp, cle_privee, cle_publique))
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 5 - probably unsupported type.
```

The variables are in french, I'm sorry ^^
So, what I want is saving this RSA public key in the database. But it appears not to be supported by Sqlite3. I've found this [Python doc](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/sqlite3.html#using-adapters-to-store-additional-python-types-in-sqlite-databases) but it explains how to adapt objects from classes you created yourself (or that's what I understood)
How do I adapt my tuple in order to save it in the table ? And then, how do I do to recover it ? (assuming that the data stored is no longer really a tuple)

And my second question is, I created a function to get back some data, but there is a small problem :)

```
def recuperer_donnee_utilisateur (identifiant, donnee):

commande = sqlite3.connect ("Base_de_donnees.db")
curseur = commande.cursor()
curseur.execute ('''SELECT ? FROM utilisateurs WHERE identifiant = ?''', (donnee, identifiant))

donnee_demandee = curseur.fetchone()
commande.close()

return donnee_demandee

>>> ajouter_utilisateur ('guil23', 'guil', 'email_adress', 'password', 687,786)
>>> recuperer_donnee_utilisateur ('guil23', 'adresse_mail')
('adresse_mail',)
```

Here, it was supposed to return 'email_adress', not the parameter I gave to the function... Why does it return 'adresse_mail' ?

Thanks for any help

EDIT :

Here I deleted the database, so you can see what happens. The function named "affichage_utilisateur () " just shows the users already saved in the database.

```
>>> affichage_utilisateurs()
>>> ajouter_utilisateur ('guil23', 'guil', 'my_email_adress', 'my_password', 687,787)
>>> affichage_utilisateurs()
(0, 'guil23', 'guil', 'my_email_adress', 'my_password', '687', '787')
>>> recuperer_donnee_utilisateur ('guil23', 'mot_de_passe') # I want my password
('mot_de_passe',)
```

There is only one user, his password is 'my_password' so I should get 'my_password' instead of a tuple with 'mot_de_passe'.
'mot_de_passe' is the name of the column where users' passwords are saved. The table is defined this way:

```
curseur.execute ('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS utilisateurs (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, identifiant TEXT, prenom TEXT, adresse_mail TEXT, mot_de_passe TEXT, cle_privee TEXT, cle_publique TEXT)''')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tuples are python objects. You won't be able to store them "as is" in a database. You would first have to convert them to a bunch of binary data, which could then be mapped back to a python object. This is called serialization, and there is a simple way of doing that in python with pickle.

That being said, it would be ugly and a really bad idea on many levels to do so (cross platform encoding, database norm, all the problematics relative to pickle in general, and so on). The best would be to split your tuple accross different columns and store them independently.

As to your second question, I don't see any blatant issue, are you sure there weren't another record in the database such that `identifiant=guil32` and who would have "adresse_mail" as email address?

About the second issue you raise. The problem is that you pass the query field through sqlite3 query sanitizer (by using the ? substitution). Therefore, the resulting sql request is interpreted as 
`SELECT 'adresse_email' FROM ...` instead of `SELECT adresse_mail FROM ...` which changes everyting.

One last thing, declaring a field `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` is enough for it to be auto incremented. You don't need your gymnastic to create a new id.

The full code working for me:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sqlite3
commande = sqlite3.connect("Base_de_donnees.db")

curseur = commande.cursor()
curseur.execute ('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS utilisateurs (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
identifiant TEXT, prenom TEXT, adresse_mail TEXT, mot_de_passe TEXT, cle_privee TEXT, cle_publique TEXT)''')

def ajouter_utilisateur(identifiant, prenom, adresse_mail, mdp, cle_privee, cle_publique):
    curseur.execute ('''INSERT INTO utilisateurs(identifiant, prenom, adresse_mail, 
    mot_de_passe, cle_privee, cle_publique) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)''', (
     identifiant, prenom, adresse_mail, mdp, cle_privee, cle_publique))
    commande.commit()

def recuperer_donnee_utilisateur (identifiant, donnee):
    curseur.execute ('''SELECT {} FROM utilisateurs WHERE identifiant = ?'''.format(donnee), (identifiant,))
    donnee_demandee = curseur.fetchone()

    return donnee_demandee

ajouter_utilisateur ('guil23', 'guil', 'email_adress', 'password', 687,786)

print recuperer_donnee_utilisateur ('guil23', 'adresse_mail')

commande.close()
```

Comment: Fine, I had thouht to split the tuple but as it will complicate the code later I wanted to see if there was another solution

Comment: :o Sorry I had not seen. I'm quite more used to forums where posts accumulate below the others ^^

Comment: Thanks for your post, it's clearer. I only want to make sure, there is no lo ger any use in the 2 first lines of ajouter_utilisateur is it ?

Comment: And in recuperer_donnees, the parameter "donnee" has no use too, so the code's working, and if I want to ask something else, should I create a function for each ? Like, recuperer_adresse_mail, recuperer_motdepasse etc

Comment: No no you're right I overlooked them. You don't need them anymore, I've updated my code. The way did is good, there is no real interest in writing a function for each field you want to retrieve.

Comment: Sure, but I mean, the function how you defined it will always give the email adress. The purpose of the string vraiable "donnee" was to be able to get password and othet data too

Comment: If i cannot use a variable then I can only define one fuction for each data

Comment: @Guil23 you can just format the query string. See the edit.

Comment: @Guil23 Cool, if you think I provided you with all that you needed don't forget to upvote the answer so it is bette referenced in the future.

Comment: Done, but my vote appears not to be taken into account